# How to build graph or tree structure using online tools

Tags: tree, graph-theory

I was looking for tools online where it helps me to create graphs or trees like below

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using windows ms paint software currently but I am getting very bad images with it.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

There is a popular tool, [neato](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/neatoguide.pdf), part of graphviz, that draws diagrams exactly like your example.